# Let $a\in X$ be a local max point for the function $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$. If $f$ has a right derivative at $a$, then $f'_+(a)\leq0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $a\in X$ be a local max point for the function $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$. If $f$ has a right derivative at $a$, then $f'_+(a)\leq0$.

Dem: If $f'_+\gt0$, then exists some $\delta$ such that $a<x<a+\delta\Rightarrow f(a)<f(x)$ then $a$ would not be a local maximum point.

This is a review from a question i found. I understand the geometric concepts behind, but i didn't get the algebric concepts, i.e. why he used $a<x<a+\delta\Rightarrow f(a)<f(x)$ if we are talking about derivative?

Comment: That is by definition of $f'_+$ existing and being positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in X\subset\Bbb{R}$ be a **local max** point for the function $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$. Then there exists some $\delta$ such that for $a<x<a+\delta$ we have $f(a)\geq f(x)$. If $f$ has right derivative at $a$, according to derivate definition
$$f'_+(a)=\lim_{x\to a+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\leq0$$